# Cant migrate tables with foreign keys

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, database-migration

im creating some migrations in my app but is giving a error of:

"General error: 1005 Can't create table+ "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")+laravel".

Cant find the problem with my migrations.

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->boolean('online');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('article_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('locale')->index();

    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('text');

    $table->unique(['article_id','locale']);
    $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: Are these in the same file? I normally have each table in a separate migration.

Comment: They are in different files

Comment: @Mick and I suppose that is a good practice. Neat coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try it separately. like this

```
Schema::table('article_translations', function($table) 
{     
    $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: This is what I do, I create both the tables, then add all my foreign keys in a separate file.

Comment: Still issues? br/